# HTML 5 Working with a canvas or canvas alternative

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to basically work with a grid whereby I can create images and place them accordingly on the grid and change the position of the grid images in real time.

I have made it using html5's

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

However, I am finding that everytime I want to remove a DrawImage or Rectangle I have to use

```
clearRect()
```

Which is a massive hassle and conflicts with overlaying images/shapes.
Is there any other way to go about doing this other than having to use

```
clearRect()
```

every time? Maybe even a completely different grid or canvas like system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the whole canvas and start again each tick. You should store the images in an array to keep track of them like:

```
[
    {
        image: "image_bottom.png",
        x: 100,
        y: 200
    },
    {
        image: "image_middle.png",
        x: 10,
        y: 200
    },
    {
        image: "image_topmost.png",
        x: 100,
        y: 20
    }
]
```

And then loop through on each tick and draw them. The first ones will be at the bottom most layer.

```
// Redraws the canvas completely
// pseudo code
function tick(){
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,element.width,element.height)

    for each in list
        draw image
};

setInterval(tick,1000/60); // draw for 60FPS
```

The tick function will render the canvas every few milliseconds, in order to get 60FPS.

Completely re-rendering is the best way to do this. You can do other ways, but you would need complicated masking and looping over pixels.

Comment: My concern is that clearing and redrawing the canvas with each tick seems like it would be very memory intensive, or am I wrong?

Comment: It isn't that memory intensive. Browsers can easily handle 60FPS canvas redrawing.